# No matching function on heap

Tags: c++

I've created a mix method which is taking two lists by reference. Than I've created mixed list(3) to which I'm assigning elements form list 1 and 2, than I return a list 3.

When I try to implement it it works in stack, but not heap.
What can be a possible problem?

(sth3 = sth3->mix(sth1,sth2);) - I have no matching function problem.

Not working:

```
    Sequence<int,string> *sth1 = new Sequence<int,string>();
    sth1->AddNode(1,"n1");
    sth1->AddNode(2,"n2");

    Sequence<int,string> *sth2 = new Sequence<int,string>();
    sth2->AddNode(10,"n1");   

    Sequence<int,string> *sth3 = new Sequence<int,string>();
    sth3 = sth3->mix(sth1,sth2);
    sth3->Print();
```

Working one:

```
    Sequence<int,string> st1;
    st1.AddNode(1,"n1");

    Sequence<int,string> st2;
    st2.AddNode(10,"n1");

    Sequence<int,string> st3;
    st3 = st3.mix(st1,st2);
    st3.Print();
```

Simplified function mix(..)

```
template<typename key,typename info>
Sequence<key, info> Sequence<key, info>::mix(const Sequence<key, info> &s1, const Sequence<key,info> &s2)
{
            Sequence<key,info> s;
            Node<key, info> *curr1 = s1.head;
            Node<key, info> *curr2 = s2.head;

            while (s.count < 10)
            {
                s.AddNode(curr1->GetId(), curr1->GetData())
                curr1 = curr1->GetNext();
                s.AddNode(curr2->GetId(), curr2->GetData())
                curr2 = curr2->GetNext();

                if (curr1 == NULL && curr2 == NULL)
                    break;

            }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: A minimal example would be sweet.

Comment: @gsamaras Added simplified implementation of mix function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `sth3 = sth3->mix(sth1,sth2)` to `*sth3 = sth3->mix(*sth1,*sth2)`.

Comment: After changing it I got error: 'class Sequence<int, std::basic_string<char> >' has no member named 'sth3'| so I think it's not the case?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense!

Comment: I mean, after doing `*sth3 = sth3->mix(*sth1,*sth2)` I get `class Sequence<int, std::basic_string<char> >' has no member named 'sth3` error instead of no matching function error.

Comment: I understood that part, but your comment doesn't make any sense when taking into consideration the code that you have provided. So I'm assuming that a part of your code is missing, hence your comment will not make any sense until you provide this missing piece of code.

Comment: I've added the missing line, maybe it changes something. The rest of the code seems to be the same. I think that's all. What part of code can I miss?

Comment: I don't see how any of the occurrences of `sth3` in your code could lead to this compilation error.

Comment: The only plausible explanation that I can think of is that you have removed the line `Sequence<int,string> *sth3 = new Sequence<int,string>();`.

Comment: So with no local variable `sth3` declared, the compiler is left to assume that it is a member of your class.

Comment: In my main() I have only 3 lines with sth3 `Sequence<int,string> *sth3 = new Sequence<int,string>();
    *sth3 = sth3->mix(*sth1,*sth2);
    sth3->Print();`

Comment: It was copying error: After checking it few times I have realized that I have *sth3 -> sth3->mix(...) instead of *sth3 = sth3->mix(...)

Answer (score 0):

In the heap one, you are giving pointer to a function that expects reference, you have to derefence them.